# Ionic 2: Client certificate based authentication HTTP request

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic2, client-certificates

Did anyone already implement a HTTP request with certificate based authentication? 
When I open the URL of my backend service with Chrome browser on my mobile phone, it is asking for client certificate, which is fine. When I open the URL in my Ionic 2 app, there is just "ERROR EMPTY RESPONSE". 
Does anyone know how to handle this? 
I am open for any ideas,
Thanks

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It looks like it is not implemented and there is no plugin for this available.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code.If you get any error please comment.

`$http({
        method: 'POST' or 'GET',
        url: //where your api locate,
        data: data,
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          //response
      }, function errorCallback(err) {
          console.log(err);
      });`

hope this will works for you :)